# C++ - Class for list with 3 elements

Tags: c++, class

I'm attempting to make a data type that is basically an associative array/map, but it would have 3 elements instead of 2. It would be implemented like this:

```
myTable rouletteBoard;
rouletteBoard.push.back(0, "Green", "Neither");
rouletteBoard.push.back(00, "Green", "Neither");
rouletteBoard.push.back(1, "Red", "Odd");
```

So really just a map or list with 3 elements, the first one being the unique key.

Yes this is a Roulette game. And I understand how to basically have a class for each number and make a separate instance for each number with the appropriate properties, but I feel that would be rather inefficient, since I could just have a list of each number with it's associated properties.

I've gotten pretty much nowhere on creating the class for this. I keep wondering if there is a better way to do it and trying that, then getting frustrated and quitting.

Comment: Just use a vector of `std::tuple`s i.e. `std::vector< std::tuple< int, std::string, std::string > >` and if you want to make sure the `int` id is unique then create a wrapper class that contains the `std::vector` and have that increment the id from 0 ( or something ), or you could use `std::find_if` to check for attempts to create duplicate keys.

Comment: The keys need to be strings if you want 0 and 00 to be unique keys. Your alternative is to code 00 as a key such as -1, but specify that its "symbol" is 
string "00" for printing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Be sure to take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for information about posting questions. Based on your question, people could make some suggestions, but a more beneficial question might include what you have already tried. I know you have been stuck for a while, but consider trying something and posting the code.

Comment: I hear ya M.K. - I wanted to stay away from posting the code I have so far for the rest of the program to keep this focused straight on my question, that now after reading it, I realize is possibly slightly ambiguous. Time to take a look at the answers, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

First let's talk about the data.  Note that `0` must be distinguished from `00` so we cannot store them both naively as integers.  Second, note that the color and parity (odd/even) can be derived instantly from the number.  There is no need to store them as separate data.  So we can do this:

```
struct Pocket {
    enum class Color { GREEN, RED, BLACK };
    enum class Parity { NONE, ODD, EVEN };

    Pocket(int8_t num) : number(num) {}

    int8_t number; // -1 for "00" on American style wheel

    Parity parity() const {
        if (number < 1) return Parity::NONE;
        if (number % 2) return Parity::ODD;
        return Parity::EVEN;
    }

    Color color() const {
        if (number < 1) return Color::GREEN;
        if (number % 2) return Color::RED;
        return Color::BLACK;
    }
};
```

Then you can make a simple container:

```
std::vector<Pocket> wheel;
for (int8_t ii = is_american ? -1 : 0; ii <= 36; ++ii) {
    wheel.emplace_back(ii);
}
```

Finally, you can add code for printing:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, Pocket pocket) {
    if (pocket.number == -1) return out << "00";
    return out << pocket.number;
}

const char* to_string(Pocket::Color color) {
    switch (color) {
        case Pocket::Color::GREEN: return "Green";
        case Pocket::Color::RED: return "Red";
        case Pocket::Color::BLACK: return "Black";
        default: return "?";
    }
}
```

Comment: double check the colors btw, as the red/bkack odd/even pattern switches several times across as standard board.

Comment: I'm following mostly everything, but this line has me perplexed: `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, Pocket pocket)` - along with the `return out <<` - I'm just unfamiliar with these.

Comment: Edit to my last comment - Just managed to find that that is how you get cout to accept a custom data type? And that's how you overload it. Never done that before.

Comment: @Ebar: Yes.  That part with `ostream` was meant to demonstrate how you can print user-defined types.  It's a pretty general and handy solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you want an associative array with multiple data, you create a map between a key and a data-structure.

For example here, if you only wanted to store strings, I'd suggest using a map between a key and a vector. Then you can add as many or as few strings as needed to each key, so it's a flexible system.

```
std::map<int,std::vector<std::string>> rouletteBoard;
```

Or, have that structure inside your "rouletteBoard" class.

As for the key, if you use literal ints, then you have a problem, as 0 and 00 would be the same int, you either need string keys, or to specify "00" interally with a special value such as -1. You can then create an enum relating to the different fields of the vector, a working prototype could look like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> rouletteBoard;

enum
{
    name,
    color,
    oddeven,
    property_count
};

std::string colors[] = { "Green", "Black", "Red"};

std::string roulette_color(int i)
{
    if (i < 1) return colors[0]; // Green
    if (i < 11) return colors[1 + (i & 1)]; // Black=Even Red=Odd
    if (i < 19) return colors[2 - (i & 1)]; // Black=Odd Red=Even
    if (i < 29) return colors[1 + (i & 1)]; // Black=Even Red=Odd
    return colors[2 - (i & 1)]; // Black=Even Red=Odd
}
int main()
{
    rouletteBoard[-1] = {"00", roulette_color(-1), "Neither"};
    rouletteBoard[ 0] = { "0", roulette_color(0), "Neither" };

    for(int i = 1; i <=36; ++i)
    {
        rouletteBoard[i] = { std::to_string(i), roulette_color(i), (i & 1) ? "Odd" : "Even" };
    }

    for (int i = -1; i <= 36; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << rouletteBoard[i][name] << ": " << rouletteBoard[i][color] << ", " << rouletteBoard[i][oddeven] << "\n";
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a vector to store a pair of strings is inefficient.

Comment: There are only approx 36 tiles on a roulette board. how many bytes are you saving by creating a custom class for that?

Comment: There are existing classes for that, `std::pair`and `std::tuple`, it’s not only about saving space but about doing unnecessary work. Also, if you don’t need ordering, would prefer `std::unordered_map` over `std::map` (although this pessimizes space).

Comment: @JasonLang: Good question!  There are 38 pockets on an American Roulette wheel.  My solution will take 38 bytes for those pockets plus three pointers (24 bytes) for the vector.  Your solution will take about 4+4+8*3+24*3 = 104 bytes per pocket due to the vector and string use.  It will then take about 2+8*2*38 bytes for the map.  That's 4562 bytes for your solution vs 62 for mine, an overhead of about 7300%.

Comment: I'll take a quick to implement solution that works for any game over a custom one, if there are only a couple of dozen locations on the board. If you're talking a game with 100x100 maps etc, or you're talking about saving the game, then of course you'd take the effort to make a custom data structure. the cost/benefit for representing the strings on something of the scale of a roulette board don't necessitate optimization. You're only going to have one copy of this per the entire program, ever.

Comment: also, re-read the question john, it was titled "C++ - Class for list with 3 elements" not "most efficient way to represent a roulette board". And he said that he already knew he could make a custom class for this, but wanted a more general solution. So maps, tuples, vectors are solutions to the actual question that was asked.